# In Tcl, how do I prevent a variable's contents from being interpreted by the shell when passed to `exec`?

Tags: tcl, interpolation, io-redirection, csh

I'm maintaining some old code and found that the following piece...

```
if {[catch {exec -- echo $html_email > $file} ret]} {
    puts $ret
    return 0
}
```

...breaks due to the first character of an HTML email being `<`, *i.e.*

```
couldn't read file "html>
    <title>cama_Investigate 00000560554PONY1</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

which is interpreted as an I/O redirect operator. Previously this wasn't an issue because we were starting the emails with some headers, *e.g.*

```
append html_email "Content-Type       : text/html; charset=us-ascii\n"
append html_email "Content-Disposition: inline\n"
```

I'm going to rewrite all this to use Tcl's native file I/O, so this question is mainly academic: What is the proper way to guard a variable's contents from being interpreted by the shell when passed to `exec`?

I'm using Tcl 8.0.5 and csh, but I'm interested in a general answer if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tcl's `exec` is funky, alas. It insists on interpreting an argument that starts with a `<` character as a redirect. (There are a few other ones too, but you're a bit less likely to hit them.) There isn't a good general workaround either except to write the data to a temporary file and redirect from that.

```
set ctr 0
while 1 {
    set filename /tmp/[pid].[incr ctr].txt
    # POSIX-style flags; write-only, must create or generate error
    if {[catch {open $filename {WRONLY CREAT EXCL}} f] == 0} break
}
puts $f $html_email
close $f
exec echo <$filename >$file
file delete $filename
```

This is horribly complicated! We can do much better by changing what program we use. If instead of using `echo` we use `cat`, we can use `exec`'s heredoc syntax:

```
exec cat <<$html_email >$file
```

Since in this case the characters are being passed directly via a pipeline (which is how Tcl does this) there's far less to go wrong. Yet it's *still* silly since Tcl's entirely capable of writing to files directly, more portably, and with less overhead:

```
set f [open $file "w"]
puts $f $html_email
close $f
```

Yes, this is actually a *hugely simplified version* of the general replacement from the first example above. Let's do the simple things that are much more obviously correct since then there's less to surprise in the future.

Comment: A `do…while` loop would be appropriate, except Tcl doesn't have them natively. An explicit `break` simplifies that.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke the intended command indirectly, routing it through a shell:

```
exec -- csh -c "echo '$html_email'" > $file
```

or

```
exec -- csh -c "exec echo '$html_email'" > $file
```

Comment: Those are very fragile, as they don't handle `'` characters (more than moderately likely to turn up in HTML) well without extra processing.